# A question about local convexity of the weak operator topology

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, topological-vector-spaces

By definition, I know a locally convex space is a topological vector space whose topology is defined by a family of seminorms $\cal P$ such that 
$$\bigcap_{p\in{\cal P}}\{x\colon p(x)=0\}=\{0\}.$$ Also I can easily show that a locally convex space by above definition separates the points and conversely. So this two properties are equivalent.

Now I want to show weak operator topology (WOT) is locally convex.

By above definition, suppose for every $\xi , \eta \in H$, $p_{\xi,\eta}(x) =0 $, thus $|(x\xi,\eta)|=0$ for every $\xi,\eta$. Put $\eta=x\xi$ we have $\|x\xi\|=0$ for every $\xi$ and we can conclude $x=0$.

My problem is to show WOT is locally convex using the equivalent property.

Suppose $x,y\in B(H)$ and $p_{h,k}(x) = p_{h,k}(y)$ for every $h,k\in H$. We have $|(xh,k)|=|(yh,k)|$. There are $r_x,r_y$ with $|r_x|=|r_y|=1$ such that $|(xh,k)|=r_x(xh,k)$ and $|(yh,k)|=r_y(yh,k)$ and in the end we can see $r_x x=r_y y$.

In this way I can not conclude wot topology separates the points. Please help me to understand it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These conditions are *not* equivalent. Take a non-zero operator $x$. Then certainly $x\neq -x$. However,

$$|(-xh, k)| = |-(xh,h)| = |(xh, k)|$$

for any $h,k\in H$.

Separation in the context of locally convex spaces means the following:

> Let $\mathscr{P}$ be a family of seminorms. Then $\mathscr{P}$ is (by definition) *separating* if for each $x\neq 0$ there exists $p\in \mathscr{P}$ such that $p(x)>0$.